# File Management and Multi Level Indexing

Tags: file, indexing, operating-system

I have the following question from my professor but I am not understanding certain concepts:

Suppose a multi-level indexing scheme in which each file has 10 direct pointers,1 pointer for single indirection, 1 for double indirection and 1 for tripled indirection. Assume that the pointers are 64 bit and each block is 256 bytes

Each block will include 256/8 = 32 pointers
The superblock(inode) will point to:
10 direct pointers
32 Single indirect
32 * 32 double indirect
32*32*32 Triple Indirect pointers
This = 10+32+1024 = 32678 pointers = 33834 blocks
33834* 256 = 8.7 mb file size

My Question relates to two items. One why are we dividing 256 by 8 to get the number of pointers per block. Two where does 33834 blocks come from? Any help would be appreciated. I have read the textbook and still I do not understand this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8 is the size of the address. (It assumes 64 bit adresses.)

`33834 = 10 + 32 + (32 * 32) + (32 * 32 * 32)` as the count of the pointers in the multiple indexing scheme.

Comment: I am assuming by size of address that you mean 2^8 can address 0 to 255 sets of bytes(for each block)?

Comment: The 8 size means that you have eight bytes for identifying the given byte in the address space. It can be represented for example with a `long` type. It can address 2^64 bytes. (In the case of 32 byte addresses it causes the 4 GB addressing limit.)

Comment: ah yes as 64 bit pointers = 8 bytes. Thank you so much.. helps me with my studying